# list files on network drive

Tags: python

I have a network drive named "EAGLE" that I mounted in ubuntu. I am trying to list every file on the root of the drive. I cannot seem to get the path correct. The drive is not offsite and is located in the office.

python

```
for item in glob.glob('\\\\localhost\\EAGLE\\Data\\*'):
  print item
```

Comment: Did you try '//localhost/EAGLE/Data/*' ? Those backslashes are wrong.

Comment: If it's mounted, running a simple "mount" should give you the mount point. Then you could just do it like with any other path...

Comment: when I right click on the drive it says the location is `network:///`

Comment: Open a terminal and type `mount` there.

Comment: 1766306, the `mount` command equinoxel mentioned will tell you what devices are mounted, and where.  Please edit the question and show the mount line for the specific network drive, and also show a shell command (for example, `ls /mnt` or `ls /mnt/xyz/`) that shows the mount point or lists the files at the root of the drive.  To make the python work you need to know the path, which is simpler in the shell.